# Ubuntu 14.04 - locales won't install libc6 (>= 2.9-0ubuntu10)

Tags: 14.04

I have a problem with locales installation.

```
sudo apt-get install locales
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 locales : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.9-0ubuntu10) but it is not going to be installed or
                    libc6.1 (>= 2.9-0ubuntu10) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: The error message seems clear: Not a 'locales' problem. You have created a version conflict by unwisely installing incompatible packages. Uninstall those packages that created the problem.

Comment: should I remove libc6?

Comment: No, you should investigate further. Determine what version of libc6 you have installed. Determine if that version of libc6 is the standard version for your release of Ubuntu. You must figure out if you are asking apt to migrate you *away* from the standard version (bad) and why...or if you are already on some non-standard version and apt is trying to *return* you to a standard version and why.

Comment: Do not add or remove packages at random. That may may break your system further. We can help you further if you edit your question to include exactly what packages or sources you were installing or changing *before* this problem occurred, since that's usually what caused the problem.

Comment: libc6 is an ESSENTIAL part of your system. Important elements of the system depend upon it. Do not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I also has a error like this.I do

> sudo apt-get clean
>
> sudo apt-get update

Comment: 'Held broken packages' could mean several different types of problems. Some are fixed by an upgrade, others are not. Perhaps you could expand your answer to explain a bit more which types of errors this will fix?